# Breaking out of finally statement without interfering with return value in try statement

Tags: python-2.7, return-value, try-finally

Alright, so i have a situation where there is a sequence which has to be executed in particular order inside try statement, if any of the steps fails, return value has to be returned. Also there is a finally statement where i perform some kind of 'go-back-to-safe-state-if-anything-fails' sequence which also has to be executed in particular order. For each step (both try and finally statement), if it fails, some kind of message has to be logged with reason why it failed and execution has to be stopped at this point. Return value of sequence inside finally statement doesn't matter to me (I'm only interested in return value of try statement). This is the way that i decided to deal with it:

```
def whatever():
    ret_val = True
    try:
        x = foo()
        if isinstance(x, str):
            print "%s" % x
            ret_val = False
            return

        y = bar()
        if isinstance(y, str):
            print "%s" % y
            ret_val = False
            return
    finally:
        a = safe_state_step_1()
        if isinstance(a, str):
            print "%s" % a
            return ret_val

        b = safe_state_step_2()
        if isinstance(b, str):
            print "%s" % b
            return ret_val
        return ret_val
```

What I want to find out if there is a more 'pythonic'/'smarter' way of dealing with this kind of situation?

Comment: The most common way is to use 'try:... except:... finally:...' block. The piece of code that might throw an exception goes in the try block.  The code for 'go-back-to-safe-state-if-anything-fails' goes in the except block. And any code that needs to be executed irrespective of the try block catches an exception or not, goes into finally block.

Comment: I'm not using try/except/finally, this is not used for catching exception, try/finally is used here to ensure block of code in finally statement is executed for sure.